# Drawing Bode plot and the meaning of the amplitude and phase

Tags: bode-plot, phase, amplitude

I'm having trouble understanding how to infer from the transfer function amplitude how to draw the Bode plot.

Given the following transfer function:

[image]

Is the amplitude the slope of the graph? When I'm looking at the analysis of the amplitude I can't relate what's written in the table to what I'm seeing.

[image]

What is the physical meaning of the amplitude and the phase shift? I understand that the amplitude gives me the intensity of the signal, but that doesn't mean much to me either. Can anyone please give me a practical example showing how this information is used in planning and designing a system?

Comment: You are asking for a book to be written. FYI. There is useful information in your table that you might take to heart, though. If \$\omega\$ is very much smaller than \$\omega_{_0}\$ then you are in one fixed situation. If \$\omega\$ is very much larger than \$\omega_{_0}\$ then you are in another fixed situation. In between, there is variation that is ***interesting***. Just a note. 1st order filters are pretty easy. But 2nd order are worth the time to study. 3rd order and beyond are too complex for most folks, so they usually try and break them into combinations of 1st order and 2nd order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This log magnitude plot (attenuation or gain) of voltage  is the "Transfer Function"  and is derived from 20log{H(ω)}.

[image]

- The vertical axis is attenuation or gain. (log1 = 0 )
- 0 dB means unity gain at low frequencies for a low pass filter (LPF)
- the frequency slope is depends if the variable is in the numerator (zero) or denominator (pole)
- 20 log that the slope is 20 dB/ decade (10) = 6 dB/ octave or multiple of 2.
- the attenuation ratio also affects phase shift of 90 degrees per "filter order" which approximately spans 2 frequency decades centred at 45 deg. per order.

  - shown is a 1st order LPF at breakpoint of ω=10 thus the formula has ω/10 in the denominator.
    [image]

### links

https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Bode/BodeRules.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiXRL4QWqIU

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question indeed.

For a practical high level example. Think of a black box with a filter inside, you can input a sine wave with 1V amplitude then you sweep the frequency of that sine wave from 1-500 Hz. In your case you will start to see an attenuation in the 1V at around 10 Hz (That's your -3dB) where the signal has lost half its power. If you keep going up in frequency you will see a higher and higher attenuation (Low pass filter).

You could also see an increase in amplitude doing the same sweep if you had a high pass filter.

As for the phase shift, that is the shift in the input vs the output in terms of voltage gain (Vout/Vin -> which is your transfer function in this case) - I've mainly used the phase plot to determine stability when working with control systems [Lecture](https://wolfweb.unr.edu/~fadali/ee370/PM_GM.pdf). I don't know if this answers your questions, but there are loads of material regarding this, I will suggest you take your time and read [this](https://web.njit.edu/~levkov/classes_files/ECE232/Handouts/Frequency%20Response.pdf) paper.

Comment: Another note is to see what happens to inductors and capacitors as you go WAY up in frequency. They become shorts/open and changes your circuitry completely. Look at the impedance formula for both components, and try to observe the impedance when you set the frequency to 0 and 10,000,000

Comment: thank you very much for the reading material! I'll try to simulate your suggestions in simulink and look at the results

Answer (score 0):

Your transfer function has a pole on the right hand side of the S plane which means an unstable system. The gain is reducing with increasing phase lead as frequency increases.

Comment: Yes - very true. And one should know that any ac analysis (magnitude) cannot reveal this instability. The amplitude response looks quite normal (as expected). It is only the increasing phase response (abnormal behaviour) which is an indication for an unstable system.

Answer (score 0):

A transfer function represents an input-output relationship. \$H(\omega )\$ or \$H(j\omega )\$is the sinusoidal transfer function. You have plotted the log-magnitude response in decibels (dB). The vertical axis is the ratio of the output amplitude to the input amplitude in decibels.$$H(j\omega) = \frac {V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = \frac {V_{O}\angle{\theta_O}}{V_{I}\angle{\theta_I}}$$

Often the input angle is taken as \$0^\circ\$.

\$V_O\$ is the output amplitude. \$V_I\$ is the input amplitude.$$|H(j\omega)| = \left| \frac {V_{O}}{V_{I}} \right|$$

What is plotted on the Bode diagram is $$Lm|H(j\omega)| = 20log{\left| \frac {V_{O}}{V_{I}} \right|}$$ where \$Lm\$ is the log-magnitude.

You have not plotted the phase response. The Bode diagram is incomplete without it. The phase of the transfer function is $$\angle {H(j\omega)} = \theta_O - \theta_I$$

This is also called the phase shift from input to output.